# XNA C# Adding objects to List in another class

Tags: xna, c#

Hi all i started creating this XNA/C# version of Space invaders to get better at xna since i've only been using it for about 4 days.

I've managed fine till now..

So my problem is adding my Bullets to a List in another class.
So i've tried working out the solution for about 3 hours now and i hope you guys can help me.

In the Player.cs class i've got a method FireBullet() wich should create a new Bullet.cs class and add it to the list in Game1.cs (it does not do this when you debug) in theory this should work(i think).

```
Linking all the corresponding classes will take too much room so i've uploaded it to github
```

https://github.com/Breinss/Space-Invaders-XNA-C-

says C in title ran out of character ment to be C# ^^

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class `Player` you are wrongly creating a new Game1 `theGame1 = new Game1();` instance. That means you are trying to run 2 games at once. This is not what you are trying to do. Your Game should only have 1 instance and that is in your `Program.cs` file in the main method which starts running your game:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (Game1 game = new Game1())
    {
        //this is where you game begins, and the Game1() constructor 
        //then initialize is called, and [ Update() , Draw() ] functions keep looping 
        game.Run();
    }
}
```

Remove `Game1 theGame1` completely from your classes and use `XNAInvaders.Game1.VariableName` instead (or you could add `using XNAInvaders;` and then use `Game1.VariableName`, but since you have all classes under the same namespace (XNAInvaders), you can simply use `Game1.VariableName` without having to add the `using` statement).

So do

```
void FireBullet()
{
   Bullet newBullet = new Bullet(position);
   newBullet.Init();
   Game1.bullets.Add(newBullet);
}
```

So basically, every variable you have in the Game1 class can be accessed by using Game1.VariableName in any other class.

However are you sure you need a `Bullet` list in your `Game1` class ? You should keep your `Game1.cs` as simple as possible. You could design it a bit better, using more classes(?) so that the `Game1.cs` isn't that messy, it really makes a difference when your game becomes more complicated (Perhaps with using something along the lines of `Level.cs` to keep the variables there)

Edit: I forgot to mention something important, you have to make your Game1 Variables **static and public** if you want to access them from other classes (because you will obviously have a single `Game1` instance right ? So why would the variables not be static)

Comment: You're the champ i litteraly looked at the code for 2-3 hours and you fix it in a few minutes.

And yes i am going to refactor the Game1 class once i'm done adding the basic functionality.

Comment: @Brein i downloaded your project and run it and i just want to add that you need previousKeyboardState and currectKeyboardState for the SpaceBar to work as you expect it to

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions like this. If you want to help, ask OP to take the question to chat or a discussion oriented forum where one-on-one help like this can take place.

Comment: @Byte56 oh ok, I guess answering off topic questions encourages people to ask them, I will know from now on